# Node.JS vm.runInNewContext() vs require() and eval()

Tags: node.js, eval, v8

- Is vm.runInNewContext considered black magic like `eval`?
- Is there a
  significant performance difference between `require` and reading a
  file and using `vm` to run it or is the the same under the hood (if
  you implemented caching etc and just wanted to add some variables to
  the context)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`runInNewContext` is not meant to be used as a replacement of `require` or `eval`, but instead as a way to create a sandbox environment where you can safely run other scripts.

Disadvantages are that it's slow (creation takes ~10 ms.) and takes up a couple megabytes. So no, don't use it as a `require` replacement.

Comment: So if I were going to use it to load a controller object (`/controllers/blog_controller.js`) and include some helpers in the context, there'd be almost no performance penalty right? (the controller is only loaded once)

Comment: Just don't do it. It's considered very bad practice for general purpose things. Why do you think you need to sandbox your own controller code?

Comment: Same reasons railway-js uses it, provide a richer context to the controllers, however, I found a pretty good solution that I like better than using `vm`. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Chris, what was your better solution?

Answer (score 12):

If you check out the code that [implements loading Modules in node.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/069dd07a1732c6a752773aaed9e8c18ab472375f/lib/module.js#L367), you'll see that require uses [vm.runInNewContext](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/069dd07a1732c6a752773aaed9e8c18ab472375f/lib/module.js#L415) or [vm.runInThisContext](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/069dd07a1732c6a752773aaed9e8c18ab472375f/lib/module.js#L426) under the hood. The `require` however, does some other extra things, like caching the module.

The [node documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) shows how the behavior is similar and different between the vm commands and eval.

So, require, eval and vm are all a little bit different, but all can be used to load code. They all have similar security issues if you are loading arbitrary code that comes from the client.

Comment: Just for the record, since the source code link to node.js above is "ancient", here is a more recent 7.10.0 source code link: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v7.10.0/lib/module.js#L543 They use `vm.runInThisContext` or `vm.runInDebugContext`. About `eval` Using a comma expression like `(0, eval)(....)` you can get the script evaluated in global scope so that it cannot pollute the local scope as shown in the node.js docu link example when you search for "eval" on the page.

Comment: "Comment maintenance": Here is a new source code link this time for node.js 11.9.0: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v11.9.0/lib/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js#L694