# What is the difference between new Function and vm?

Tags: node.js

I'd like to know what is the difference between [new Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) (in effect – [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)) and [`vm`](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) module.

On the surface, these appear to be similar:

- Both can be restricted to a specific context (using [`context`](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_vm_createcontext_sandbox) in `vm` and using [parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function#Parameters) in `Function` constructor).
- `vm` can re-use context between multiple invocations using [`runInContext`](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_script_runincontext_contextifiedsandbox_options). `new Function` can re-use the same context using parameters.

However, a simple benchmark shows quite significant performance difference between `vm` and `new Function`. Therefore, I am assuming there is an underlying difference to how each of these operate.

I'd like to understand the difference in order to make an educated decision when to use which tool.

---

I am aware that there is a similar question ([Node.JS vm.runInNewContext() vs require() and eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9867069/node-js-vm-runinnewcontext-vs-require-and-eval/9872462)). However, that question has gone into discussing the difference between `eval` and `require`. It does not address the difference between `eval` and `vm` module.

Answer (score 4):

Here's some code to show some differences:

```
const vm = require('vm');

globalName    = 'global';
var localName = 'local';

function code(prefix) {
  return `console.log("${prefix}:", typeof globalName, typeof localName)`;
}

eval(code('eval'));

new Function(code('function'))();

vm.runInThisContext(code('vm, this ctx'));
vm.runInNewContext(code('vm, new ctx'));
```

Its output:

```
eval: string string
function: string undefined
vm, this ctx: string undefined
evalmachine.<anonymous>:1
console.log("vm, new ctx:", typeof globalName, typeof localName)
^

ReferenceError: console is not defined
```

So:

- `eval` can access both global and local variables
- `new Function` can access global variables, but no local variables
- `vm.runInThisContext()` can access the same as `new Function` can
- `vm.runInNewContext()` can't even access global variables like `console`

The `vm` functions have some additional functionality, like being able to pass a timeout to limit the runtime of the code.

From a security standpoint, `vm.runInNewContext()` is the most restricted. It won't even allow `require()` without the `require` function explicitly being passed in through the sandbox object.

Comment: Hmm, looks like `new Function` can *create* local variables in node.js .  Check out the answer to my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46440029/how-can-i-dynamically-create-a-variable-dynamically-in-the-current-scope-in-java#46440182

Comment: No, in that example, it is setting a global. By removing your `eval` `var`, the global became apparent to the setting of `a.b` in the module code and thus to the logging.

Comment: Ah, I see... scary