# How can I dynamically create a variable dynamically in the current scope in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to dynamically create node.js variables that point to objects.

I know I can create a variable dynamically in scope using eval:

```
var vars = ['a','b']
for(var n=0; n<vars.length; n++) {
   eval('var '+vars[n]+' = '+n)
}

console.log(b) // prints 1
```

The above dynamically creates variables and gives them a value of whatever their index is inside the `vars` list.

But what if I want to set these dynamic variables to an object reference? Something like the following:

```
var vars = {a: {}, b:{}}
for(var k in vars) {
   eval('var '+k) // create the variable dynamically
   new Function('value', k+' = value')(vars[k]) // attempt to set the value
}

a.b = 5
console.log(vars.a.b) // undefined : (
```

I know why the above doesn't work - the function created by `new Function` can't see the current scope, and so can't set the value. Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do, such that `console.log(vars.a.b)` would print "5" rather than "undefined"?

UPDATE:

Hmm, I was wrong that `new Function` can't see or modify variables in the local scope, since this works:

```
var obj = {}
eval('var x')
new Function('value', 'x = value')(obj)

obj.a = 5
console.log(x.a) // prints 5
```

So now I'm pretty confused why my loop above doesn't seem to work..

UPDATE 2:

I just realized that my code actually *does* work in chrome's console. But its not working in node.js...

UPDATE JUST FOR PHIL:

Here's my situation. I'm using [Parsimmon](https://github.com/jneen/parsimmon/blob/master/API.md) to build a parser combinator. This is how that's done:

```
var L = Parsimmon.createLanguage({
  combinator1: function() {
     return Parsimmon.string('hi')
  },
  combinator2: function() {
     return L.combinator1.many()
  }
})
```

I'd like to eliminate the need to write `L.` before every parser combinator I write. I could do this:

```
var combinator2 = L.combinator2
```

But that would require me to add an additional line like that for every combinator I write. As you can see, I can't use `with` since `L` is created after I'd be able to write `with(L)` and if I define my functions below then use them in the object, I'm back to duplicating those function names every time i write a new combinator.

So to summarize, I'd like to loop through `L` and put all the generated parser combinators into a nice clean variable in scope so I can write `combinator1` instead of `L.combinator1` (etc).

Comment: I dont know the answer .. but just want to know why do you want to do that ? I have never have felt the need to do that :)

Comment: the `(var[k])` looks suspicious. Should be `(vars[k])`? Nothing to do with answering your question though.

Comment: I can't even tell what you're trying to do here. Your function body create a new variable inside its own scope and assigns a value but nothing ever comes of that expression. Did you just want to omit the `var` keyword inside your function?

Comment: @nilobarp Yup, typo!

Comment: @HarshalCarpenter Looking to splay out variables created in an object that I don't control (generated by a module) into the local  scope so I can access them without the object prefix. Will make my parser look cleaner : D

Comment: @BT that sounds like the worst reason to do something like this

Comment: @phil Thanks for the sage insight

Comment: @BT you're welcome :) I mean, if the entire idea is to omit the object prefix, you might as well just wrap everything in [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with), eg `with(objectPrefix) { console.log(prop) }`. Can't be any worse than `eval`

Comment: @Phil I could do that, but in my case it would require me duplicating all my function names, since the functions that need these variables are passed into the function that creates those variables. Definitely a slight step up, but still not ideal. +1 for the good idea tho!

Comment: This really fits the definition of an [*"X/Y problem"*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why don't you explain clearly what it is you're trying to achieve instead of how you think it should be achieved.

Comment: @Phil I updated my question for ya

Comment: Couldn't you use `this.combinator1` instead of `L.combinator1`...?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Maybe, but doesn't really solve my problem of removing extraneous boilerplate does it?

Comment: @BT that wouldn't be "extraneous boilerplate", it would be a properly self-referencing, internalized module.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Ok, but not what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, whether or not there are better ways to achieve your goal, if you just remove `'var '` on the dynamic `Function`, it will operate on the outer (global) scope.

Change:

```
new Function('value', k+' = value')(vars[k])
```

to:

```
new Function('value', k+' = value')(vars[k])
```

So:

```
var vars = {a: {}, b:{}}
for(var k in vars) {
   eval('var '+k) // create the variable dynamically
   new Function('value', k+' = value')(vars[k]) // attempt to set the value
}

a.b = 5
console.log(vars.a.b)
```

You don't want to declare a new variable with local scope inside the function, you want to operate on the outer scope.

**Update to address new question**

Your first loop does work. Try introspecting on `a` or `b`; they are as should be expected, 0 and 1, respectively.

**Update 2 based on info this is for Node.js**

Per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function , `Function` always works on the global scope. In Node, this is on `global` and `var` variables are not the global scope but are the module's scope. To fix this for Node, you can do the following and omit your `eval` `var` declaration (which was overriding for the module the global scope which you have access to inside `Function`):

```
var vars = {a: {}, b:{}}
for(var k in vars) {
   new Function('value', k +' = value')(vars[k]) // attempt to set the value
}

a.b = 5
console.log(vars.a.b) // 5
```

In other words, the inner function sets variables which automatically become accessible via `global`, so your module code, in the absence of any module-scoped `var` declarations of `a` overwriting the global, you can set the global `a` properties as with the line `a.b = 5`.

**Update 3**

Since I had just been addressing your issue in understanding `Function`, I gave the above information. As per your follow-up comment (and again, without speaking to its suitability for your specific use case), you can operate on the object via `eval` as follows:

```
var vars = {a: {}, b:{}}
for(var k in vars) {
   eval('var '+k+' = vars["'+k+'"]')
}

a.b = 5
console.log(vars.a.b) // 5
```

But to reiterate the warnings made by others--using `eval` is generally not a good idea and can be dangerous when the variables referenced include arbitrary user data...

Comment: Hm, that was actually just a typo. My actual code is identical to what you wrote there. I noticed that this *does* work in a browser, but not in node.js - which is where I'm trying to do this. I'll add a node.js tag.

Comment: Yeah, the first loop works fine in node.js. I get a console log that prints 1. But the problem is in assigning those dynamically created variables an object value that can't be stringified. That second loop that loops through the object keys is what I'd like to have work in node.js

Comment: Hey, I'm amazed that worked! Especially after reading the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39416716/what-is-the-difference-between-new-function-and-vm . But thanks!

Comment: Just be aware that this is different from your original code in that now it is setting on `global`--a less safe practice as it sets `a` for not only this module but for any application code running this module. I am just demonstrating that it is possible to be done this way as `Function` will work on the global scope. But again, not a good practice typically.

Comment: Oh hmmm, that's a little scary. There's no way around this?

Comment: Oh my gosh, I'm so dumb! There's a much simpler (and safer) way to do this! All I have to do is loop through the object and do `eval('var '+k+' = object["'+k+'"]')`. I'd write up the answer myself, but you deserve to have your answer chosen. Mind updating?

Comment: I don't believe there's any way around it, as the module variables are private, and there doesn't seem to be any global that lets you reach into them (except possibly if they are exposed as exports on the module object). What is `object` in your example?

Comment: `object` is some object in scope. If you look at my "update just for phil", the object is `L`. I can't believe I didn't see the easy solution before

Comment: Updated based on your prior example. FWIW, there are advantages & disadvantages of trying to pin people as yourself down on use cases, as sometimes there is insight and information to be gained in understanding why even a bad approach works or doesn't. I didn't ask in this case, as I thought it helpful to focus on what your code was doing, rather than digging into what you are trying to do. I would suggest in future that if you want the best answer, you bring up what you are trying to do. But frankly, I can get annoyed when people ask, as I'm often just trying to learn about the language.

Comment: Thanks! I'm the same way : )

Comment: Just ingeniously!

Answer (score 0):

change this line :

```
from : 
a.b = 5

to
vars.a.b = 5
```

because a is undefined in your case that's why it is now allowing to create a new property

vars.a will return you a object not only a as a is vars property.

Comment: `a` should have been defined via the `eval` line